# excel formula series fill in custom order

Tags: excel

i have two table of excel

1st/

```
 1   |     blawa1     |blawb1     |blawc1     |blawd1     |   
 2   |     blawa2     |blawb2     |blawc2     |blawd2     |   
 3   |     blawa3     |blawb3     |blawc3     |blawd3     |
 ...
```

2nd/ that should be linked to 1st table in the folowing form

```
 1   |     blawa1    |    
 2   |     blawb1    |    
 3   |     blawc1    |    
 4   |     blawd1    |    
 5   |               |
 6   |     blawa2    |    
 7   |     blawb2    |    
 8   |     blawc2    |    
 9   |     blawd2    |    
10   |               |
11   |     blawa3    |    
12   |     blawb3    |    
13   |     blawc3    |    
14   |     blawd3    |    
15   |               |
16   |     blawa4    |    
17   |     blawb4    |    
18   |     blawc4    |    
19   |     blawd4    |    
20   |               |
...
```

when i write the formula  in table 2 and drag it down, the formula did not fill in series that i want. 
e.g: it jump from "blawa1" to "blawa6" , while it should be "blawa2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in columns **A** through **D**, pick some cell, say **F4**, and enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/5,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,5))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Using similar formulas, any two dimensional table can be mapped into a single column or a single row.

If you see zeros in the output single column rather than the spaces, fill column **E** with blanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below formula

```
=IF(INDIRECT(CHAR(64+MOD(ROW()+4,5)+1) & (INT((ROW()-1)/5)+1))=0,"",INDIRECT(CHAR(64+MOD(ROW()+4,5)+1) & (INT((ROW()-1)/5)+1)))
```

copy the this cell to required number of times.